# Where can I find Wi-Fi signal strength monitor in Mountain Lion?

Tags: mac, wireless-networking, osx-mountain-lion

In OS X Lion, I often used Wi-Fi diagnostics tool ([screen](http://osxdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/monitor-wireless-signal.jpg), [link](http://www.macworld.com/article/1162117/monitor_wi_fi_with_lions_hidden_tool.html)) to report proper wifi signal level, since the wifi icon next to the clock in OS X menubar isn't reliable at all. (It shows full signal level even I'm too far from my router for internet connection to work...)

I can't find it in Mountain Lion. Is this functionality removed?

EDIT: Yes, the app is still there. The main screen looks slightly different though.

**Lion:**
[image: Lion]

**Mountain Lion:**
[image: ML]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality is *not* removed in Mountain Lion. It's still in the same spot as Lion.

[image: /System/Library/CoreServices/]

Comment: Please clarify your answer; I don't see how this is an answer, you're just repeating the OP's observations, including a link to the same web page.

Comment: skub, the app is different on Mountain Lion, are you able to show wifi signal levels? I couldn't find it. I've just connected OS X Lion backup and copied the app from there – it seems to work fine.

Comment: Yeah, they changed it around a bit. Do a command (Apple button) and hit number 5 or 6 and it will bring up the wifi scan that shows levels and the performance tab. Check under the *View* menu to see all the options.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest for mountain lion is to hold ALT and click on WiFi icon in menubar then "Open WiFi diagnostics"  and (ignore main screen) then View->Wifi Scan for easy signal strength graph.

There is no "View" menu in the Wireless Diagnosticts app in 10.8.4. But you'll find a "Performance" tool in the window that opens after selecting "Utilities" under the "Window" menu of the app.

Comment: Thanks - this answer supercedes the accepted answer if using version 10.8.4